# Crash in C program compiled with MSVC when trying to read a file with diffrent encoding then system locale

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, encoding, locale

### Background

Program uses system locale `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`. Usually on Windows this means some one byte encoding (depending on language version of Windows): Windows-1250, Windows-1252, Latin US, ....

Now input file is in different encoding (lest assume Utf-8). Program should load properly this file into a memory and print it using encoding provided by system locale.

### MCVE

Here is Minimal Complete Verifiable Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void copyTextFiles(FILE* in, FILE* out)
{
    char buff[1024];
    while(fscanf(in, "%1023[^\n]%*[\n]", buff) == 1) {
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", buff);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char * l = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    if (!l) {
        perror("setlocale");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Locale selected: %s\n", l);
    FILE *file = fopen("example_utf-8.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");
    if (!file) {
        perror("example_utf-8.txt");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("File was opened\n");
    copyTextFiles(file, stdout);
    fclose(file);
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Some random input file `example_utf-8.txt`:

```
ąłóę
ąłóę
+−-
ÀÁÂÃĀĂȦÄẢ
ḂƁƇȨɃÆǼĶɈǨỒỐŔṘȟḧƕ
ɋƥṗ
```

### Problem

This code is aligned with MSVC documentation:
[fopen, _wfopen | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170#unicode-support)

> ### Unicode support
>
> **`fopen`** supports Unicode file streams. To open a Unicode file, pass a `ccs=encoding` flag that specifies the desired encoding to **`fopen`**, as follows.
>
> `FILE *fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");`
>
> Allowed values for **`ccs`** encoding are `UNICODE`, **`UTF-8`**, and **`UTF-16LE`**.

But program crashes, with following call stack:

```
>   ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_stdio_char_traits<char>::validate_stream_is_ansi_if_required(_iobuf * const stream) Line 495   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__crt_stdio_input::stream_input_adapter<char>::validate() Line 98 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__crt_stdio_input::input_processor<char,__crt_stdio_input::stream_input_adapter<char>>::process() Line 1092   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!common_vfscanf::__l2::<lambda>() Line 47  C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) &,void <lambda>(void)>(__acrt_lock_stream_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, common_vfscanf::__l2::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_stream_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 202 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_lock_stream_and_call<int <lambda>(void)>(_iobuf * const stream, common_vfscanf::__l2::int <lambda>(void) && action) Line 297   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!common_vfscanf<char>(const unsigned __int64 options, _iobuf * const stream, const char * const format, __crt_locale_pointers * const locale, char * const arglist) Line 36    C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__stdio_common_vfscanf(unsigned __int64 options, _iobuf * stream, const char * format, __crt_locale_pointers * locale, char * arglist) Line 60    C++
    read_file.exe!_vfscanf_l(_iobuf * const _Stream, const char * const _Format, __crt_locale_pointers * const _Locale, char * _ArgList) Line 1068  C
    read_file.exe!fscanf(_iobuf * const _Stream, const char * const _Format, ...) Line 1210 C
    read_file.exe!copyTextFiles(_iobuf * in, _iobuf * out) Line 8   C
    read_file.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 28 C
    [External Code]
```

Top of callstack points to `_VALIDATE_STREAM_ANSI_RETURN`:

```cpp
template <>
struct __acrt_stdio_char_traits<char> : __crt_char_traits<char>
{
    static int_type const eof = EOF;

    static bool validate_stream_is_ansi_if_required(FILE* const stream) throw()
    {
        _VALIDATE_STREAM_ANSI_RETURN(stream, EINVAL, false);
        return true;
    }
};
```

So underneath C library is using C++, but it is unclear to me what this check exactly do and why it fails (crashes).

### CPP version which works

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale sysLocale("");
    std::locale utfLocale(".utf-8");
    std::locale::global(utfLocale);
    std::cout.imbue(sysLocale);
    std::cout << "Locale: " << sysLocale.name() << '\n';
    
    std::ifstream file("example_utf-8.txt");
    if (!file) {
        std::perror("example_utf-8.txt");
        return 2;
    }
    file.imbue(utfLocale);
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "\nDONE\n";
}
```

It works perfectly it is converting characters if sustem locale do not support specyfic character, here is output of `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>chcp 65001

C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>cpp_read_file.exe
Locale:
ąłóę
ąłóę
+−-
ÀÁÂÃĀĂȦÄẢ
ḂƁƇȨɃÆǼĶɈǨỒỐŔṘȟḧƕ
ɋƥṗ


DONE

C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>chcp 437
Active code page: 437

C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>cpp_read_file.exe
Locale:
alóe
alóe
+--????
AAAAAA?Ä?
?????Æ?K?K??R????
???


DONE

C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\repo\mixEncodingsInC\build\Debug>cpp_read_file.exe
Locale:
alóe
alóe
+--????
ÀÁÂÃAA?Ä?
?????Æ?K?K??R????
???


DONE
```

### Question

Why it crashes? Did I misunderstood something in documentation? Can I make something to make it work?

### Notes

- Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31933 for x64
- Window 10 Ent Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045
- git repo if someone wish to try: https://github.com/MarekR22/mixEncodingsInC.git

Comment: Hmm. Removing the `, ccs=UTF-8` from your C code prevents the crash. Not sure why ... but does your text file have a BOM (the test I made does)? If so, that will anyway override any encoding you specify.

Comment: I think you also have issues with the `%[...]` specifier. You should be reading `wchar_t` from a UTF-8 file and I'm not sure how to specify wide chars in that format.

Comment: Note that `while(fscanf(in, "%1023[^\n]%*[\n]", buff) == 1)` is bogus: it will stop immediately if the file starts with an empty line, silently break long lines into smaller ones and delete empty lines... Just use `while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in)) { fputs(buf, out); }`

Comment: Never blindly trust any Microsoft documentation that says anything about UTF-8. Ask me how I know.

Comment: @AdrianMole because it doesn't try to transcode from UTF-8 to the system code page.

Answer (score 0):

What is interesting modifying C code this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void copyTextFiles(FILE* in, FILE* out)
{
    char buff[1024];
    while(fscanf(in, "%1023[^\n]%*[\n]", buff) == 1) {
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", buff);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char * l = setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf-8");
    if (!l) {
        perror("setlocale");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Locale selected: %s\n", l);
    FILE *file = fopen("example_utf-8.txt", "rt+");
    if (!file) {
        perror("example_utf-8.txt");
        return 2;
    }

    printf("File was opened\n");
    copyTextFiles(file, stdout);
    fclose(file);
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Makes it print proper characters in console even if system locale (code page) do changes.

So looks like `printf` takes into account system locale and program `setlocale` set encoding used by program (so it is analogs to `std::locale::global(utfLocale);` in cpp example).

Problem still remains I'd like to read file with different encoding then used by application.

Answer (score 0):

Everything UTF-8 in MSVC documentation and libraries seems to be written by a bunch of monkeys. For example:

> FILE *fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");
>
> Allowed values for ccs encoding are UNICODE, UTF-8, and UTF-16LE.
>
> When a file is opened in Unicode mode, input functions translate the data that's read from the file into UTF-16 data stored as type wchar_t. Functions that write to a file opened in Unicode mode expect buffers that contain UTF-16 data stored as type wchar_t. If the file is encoded as UTF-8, then UTF-16 data is translated into UTF-8 when it's written. The file's UTF-8-encoded content is translated into UTF-16 when it's read. An attempt to read or write an odd number of bytes in Unicode mode causes a parameter validation error.

This looks like a straight copy-paste from the wfopen documentation. None of this UTF-16 business makes any sense in the narrow character context.

But if we squint hard enough, we may deduce that `ccs=UTF-8` means "read as UTF-8 *and transcode to my current encoding, whatever it is*" (could be UTF-16 if using a wide stream, or any of the "ANSI" code pages if not). But then why a transcode failure should result in a crash is beyond me. This makes `ccs=UTF-8`, in the read mode at least, unusable in any real-life software. Ask Microsofties what they think about it. Anyway, this behaviour is not what you want. The very next sentence in the documentation tells you what to do (but then given the overall quality of the documentation, verify it yourself).

> To read or write data that's stored in your program as UTF-8, use a text or binary file mode instead of a Unicode mode. You're responsible for any required encoding translation.